# Style only first level of unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have a list like so:

```
    <ul id="main">
        <li>January
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>February
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to affect only the first level of li's - I thought this css would do the trick, but it appears to be not working correctly.

```
#main > li {
cursor: pointer;
list-style-image: url('plus_sign.gif');
}
```

The child lists still have a plus symbol next to them ... what would I be doing wrong?

Comment: Sure you don't have another rule somewhere? http://jsfiddle.net/YA2yx/

Comment: Almost positive I don't have another rule...when I paste your jsfiddle into my html file and display it locally, it shows up with the cats on every li.

Comment: (Sorry about the cats). If you inspect the elements in your favorite browser tools, it should show you what CSS rule is being applied.

Comment: Looks like the rule is being applied to all li elements.  No idea what would be causing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this css, it looks like what you want.

```
#main{
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style-image:url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sqpurple.gif');
}
#main ul{
    /*If you don't want the hallow circles*/
    list-style:none;
    /*if you want the hollow cirles, remove list-style and uncomment list-style-image:none
     list-style-image:none;
    */
}
```

It will display the plus_sign.gif(sqpurple.gif in this case) only on January and February.
See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aCj9A/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm starting to wonder if there's something going on that in my environment because I've typed character for character and still nothing. Frustrating.

Comment: Maybe you should try it in a new file, just these rules alone or even something simpler to try and find the source of your problem. Hope it works out for you in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
  #main  li {
    list-style-image: none;
  }    
  #main > li {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-image: url('plus_sign.gif');
  }
```

list-style-image is an inheritable property so it takes the value from its parent.

Comment: After copying and pasting your css in, it puts them all back to their default list bullets. the solid bullet and then the hallow.

Comment: @oshft91 Change "plus.png" to "plus_sign.gif"

Comment: Yeah, I caught that - no go.  Going to try and start a complete new .html and .css file.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to explain that it's an inheritable property.

Answer (score 0):

add another rule to deal with all other cases of li's:

```
ul > li{
    color: red;
    /*specifically*/
    list-style-image: none;
}
```

Give the css a default so your specific case will be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Create another style and modify the ul to utilize the class:

```
.main > li {
cursor: pointer;
list-style-image: url('imageurl');
}
.main > li > ul > li {
cursor: auto;
list-style-image: none;
}

<ul class="main">
    <li>January
        <ul>
            <li> test</li>
            <li>test2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>February
        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```